# form not visible on browser even with my get and post methods implemented in django 10.5

Tags: django

```
class Profile(View):
    """User Profile page reachable from /user/<username> URL"""
    def get(self, request, username):
        params = dict()
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        tweets = Tweet.objects.filter(user=user)
        params["tweets"] = tweets
        params["user"] = user
        return render(request, 'profile.html', params)

class PostTweet(View):
    """Tweet Post form available on page /user/<username> URL"""
    def post(self, request, username):

        form = TweetForm(self.request.POST)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if form.is_valid():
                user = User.objects.get(username=username)
                tweet = TweetForm(text=form.cleaned_data['text'],
                user=user,
                country=form.cleaned_data['country'])
                tweet.save()
                words = form.cleaned_data['text'].split(" ")

                for word in words:
                    if word[0] == "#":
                    hashtag,created=HashTag.objects.get_or_create(name=word[1])
                    hashtag.tweet.add(tweet)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/'+user)
            else:
                form = TweetForm()
                return render(request, 'profile.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: Please state your problem clearly and properly format code.

Comment: This is my view which i made sure to include the else: incase i my request is from a get method. i also used the form.is_valid() method as i read in most topics like this but the form element is still not visible. i only see the post button.

Comment: Edit your initial question. You have some code formatting issues. And add a question.

Answer (score 0):

You must make both methods in a single view class.
So on get user gets empty form, and on post form gets processed.